# Adding userInfo to NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

For a project I'm working on, I need to be doing several simultaneous plist uploads with an NSURLConnection, and it'd be neat to have a userInfo property to keep track of stuff.

I have:

```
// header
@interface NSURLConnection ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) id userInfo;

@end

// implementation
@implementation NSURLConnection ()

@synthesize userInfo = _userInfo;

@end
```

When I try to compile, it says it expects an identifier in the parens. When I give it an identifier, making it a category, it becomes incredibly offended that I want to synthesize in the category. When I remove the parens entirely, the worst nightmare occurs: it compiles. Unfortunately, NSURLConnection becomes ambiguous, with mine overwriting the real one. It's great at holding userInfo, but absolutely nothing else.

Has anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with alternative approach by considering **inheriting** your a class from  `NSURLConnection`.

Here check the simple and alternative solution for [(BROKEN LINK) adding state to `NSURLConnection`](http://www.goosoftware.co.uk/blog/adding-state-to-nsurlconnection/)

**EDIT:** Link broken, here's a better one:
http://web.archive.org/web/20110116033842/http://www.goosoftware.co.uk/blog/adding-state-to-nsurlconnection/

(Thanks, wjl)

Comment: @Alex: It now appears on the wayback machine. http://web.archive.org/web/20110116033842/http://www.goosoftware.co.uk/blog/adding-state-to-nsurlconnection/

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question in the context of iPhone OS 3. If you're targeting iOS 5 or above, you probably want to use `+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]` with blocks.